# Como eu faço a paginação por categorias e tags?

Tags: php, mysql, paginação, crud

Eu estou criando um projeto, site de noticias, e tenho que fazer uma paginação usando categorias e tags, uma noticia tem uma categoria e mais de uma tag.

Tenho uma tabela com as postagens de noticias, e tenho as tabelas com categorias e tags, oque exatamente eu quero saber, é como relacionar uma categoria e varias tags a uma uma noticia.

Comment: Você criou o relacionamento entre as tabelas no banco de dados? Se não, você conhece os relacionamentos um-para-um, um-para-muitos e muitos-para-muitos?

Comment: Não conheço, eu comecei a um mês a estudar php, estou criando um projeto para praticar.

Comment: Oi Caymmi, fica mais fácil de entender o que você está tentando fazer com o código das tabelas. Geralmente você resolve isso com uma fk (`categoria_id`) na tabela `noticia` (já que uma noticia pode ter só uma categoria) e uma tabela de relacionamento `tag_noticia` com `fks / pk` = `tag_id` e `noticia_id` (já que uma notícia pode ter várias tags)

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, eu pensava que isso era feito no php, vou estudar mysql.